# MarkerWithLabel mouseOver issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put a little div in the labelContent of my Markers when the 'mouseover' event is triggered.

But the problem is that everytime the mouse moves (inside that div) the mouseout event is triggered..
Without DOM Elements it works fine, but if I put some divs, img etc the problem starts happening.

I'm using the basic.html from markerWithLabel page, with some modifications

```js
function initMap() {
     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var markers = [];
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
       zoom: 12,
       center: latLng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
    
     var text = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/careers-logo.png?v=4daa70d5b71e">AAAAAAAAAA<br><br>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBB<p> ALFA </p> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB<br><br>BBBBB';  
     var html = '<div id="" style="margin-top:2px">'+
                          '<div>'+
                              '<div width="285">'+              
                                    
                                      '<div width="90" height="80" align="center" style="vertical-align: top">'+
                                          '<div style="display:inline-block;margin-top: 12px;">'+
                                            '<img src="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Img/logos/careers-logo.png?v=4daa70d5b71e" width="80" height="52">'+
                                          '</div>'+
                                      '</div>'+
                                      '<div width="185" align="left" style="color:#FFF; font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'+
                                        '<div style="display:inline-block;height:80px;margin-top: 2px;overflow:hidden" title="TITULO DO MARCADOR" alt="ALT DO MARCADOR">'+
                                            '<div style="font-family: arial,tahoma;line-height: 14px;color:white"><strong>TITULO DO MARCADOR</strong><br> 6 quartos<br>Valor: 15000000 <br>Area: 120 m2</p>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                      '</div>'+                                                                   
                              '</div>'+
                          '</div>'+
                      '</div>';


     var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: homeLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       pane: "overlayMouseTarget" ,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA425K",
       labelNovo: text,
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
     });
    
     markers.push(marker1);

     var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.475, -123.84),
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       pane: "overlayMouseTarget",
       labelContent: "$395K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}
     });
     markers.push(marker2);


     var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers /*, mcOptions fix javascript error */);
    
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function (e) {  console.log('mouseover'); this.set('labelContent',this.labelNovo); });
     
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseout", function (e) { console.log('mouseout'); this.set('labelContent','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz') });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseover", function (e) { this.set("labelContent",html) });
     
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseout", function (e) { this.set("labelContent",'OUTOUTOUTOTU') });
     
     
     window.map = map;
    
   }
```

```css
.labels {
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     max-height: 500px !important;
     width: 100px;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>MarkerWithLabel Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
 <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
<p>A basic example of markers with labels. Note that an information window appears whether you
click the marker portion or the label portion of the MarkerWithLabel. The two markers shown here
are both draggable so you can easily verify that markers and labels overlap as expected.</p>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
 <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've set 2 markers to show the difference.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: mcOptions is not defined` on your code snippet

Comment: @geocodezip oh ok you are right, I'm sorry I removed some of my markerclusterer references to make this example and I have forgotten this one. You can ignore this :), my problem is just with the markerWithLabel

Comment: @geocodezip please don't ignore the answer just because of that little mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`relatedTarget`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljccxdqe.php)-property of the events(mouseover/mouseout).

When it's `undefined`(happens when the event has been triggered by the marker) or when the 
`relatedTarget` is not within the node representing the label(includig the label itself) set the `labelContent`. Otherwise do nothing.

A possible implementation:

```
  function MarkerWithLabelAndHover(marker){   
    if(marker.get('hoverContent')){
      marker.set('defaultContent',marker.get('labelContent'))
      var fx=function(e,m){
        var r=e.relatedTarget;
        if(!r){
           return true;
        }
        while(r.parentNode){
          if(r.className==m.labelClass){
            return false;
          }
          r=r.parentNode;
        }
         return true;

      }
      marker.set('defaultContent',marker.get('labelContent'))
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(e){
        var that=this;
        if(fx(e,this)){
            this.set('labelContent', this.get('defaultContent'));
        }

    });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(e){
        var that=this;
        if(fx(e,this)){
            this.set('labelContent', this.get('hoverContent'));
          }

    });
    }

    return marker;
  }
```

The function expects as argument a `MarkerWithLabel`-instance. The passed object may have a property named `hoverContent`(the desired content you like to apply on mouseover). When it does the mentioned behaviour will be applied to the marker.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m6wazLrf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m6wazLrf/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried to log the relatedTarget but none of them threw me 'undefined'. 
I've put it inside "google.maps.event.addListener" mouseOver event..

"console.log(event.relatedTarget);"  - like this

It seems that when I 'hover' the <p>ALFA</p> element for example, the mouseOut event is triggered.. But I couldn't figure out how to use your suggestion